# Trying to mirror a legacy PHP 5.3.29 app on CentOS 7 (strange I know!)

Tags: php, centos7, mamp, php53

I'm wondering if any linux/php gurus out there could help. Long story short, i've been tasked with creating a mirror/backup of a website which is made in **PHP 5.3.29** to mitigate any risks if the existing server fails for any reason.

The app is huge and legacy and written in **PHP 5.3.29**. I have tried to download it locally and get it running on my local **MAMP** instance using the most up to date version of PHP, but due to the difference between 5.3.29 and the current version, the app fails all over the place. I have suggested that the app be re-written going forward but for the interim solution I need to get this working.

I have got a **CentOS 7** server set up with the latest version of PHP installed, but obviously I know this is going to fail, I have had a look online and haven't been able to find a good solution.

Does anyone have any recommendations (I have only been working directly with Linux servers for a few months so i'm still new to some areas). on how I can get PHP 5.3.29 running on CentOS 7?

Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: Try to replicate the old environment (which base OS?) inside a VM, and check if your app works with the (heavily patched) PHP 5.3.3 as supplied by CentOS 6.

Comment: It's a WHM server running RHEL 5.11! I'll spin up a Centos 6 VM and see if it helps. Just wasn't sure if there was a way of getting a version that old on CentOS 7

Comment: Your app may currently be _running_ on PHP 5.3.29, but if it "fails all over the place" on a current version, then it was _written_ for an even older version of PHP, 5.2 or even older, _and never maintained_. For many years. If this app is even marginally important to your business, then the company needs to address this problem.

Comment: Hi Michael, it works perfectly on 5.3.29, I just want to mimic the environment in a backup server with the same versions. My idea is to have a load balancer (HA Proxy) which switches over to the back up if the original server fails.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case anyone was wondering, I ended up setting up a CentOS 7 cloud server and installing PHP 5.4 through:

```
yum install php
```

However I could also set up a CentOS 5 server and then install php 5.3.29 using the Webtatic repo [here](https://webtatic.com/packages/php53/)

I had some problems at first but it was mainly down to the default apache config not having mod rewrite enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the IUS archives and install the RPM's manually on CentOS 6.
https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/archive/CentOS/6/x86_64/

Download them all and installing with yum will solve any dependencies you might need.